# What are the default organization IAM permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, roles, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have been messing about in a GCP account and have severely goofed IAM role permissions.

What is the default set of Users/serviceAccounts and their roles in a new organization? I do not want to lock myself out of managing my organization, but I want to revert to the "out of the box" settings.

Update:
   I am looking for the result of only having default permissions at the org level of my Google Cloud Account, basically to start over. I spent a lot of time playing around with IAM roles and simply want the configuration for my IAM to be as if I started a new organization.

Comment: can you be more specific about what isn't working, and how you'd like it to work?

Comment: Do you want to know what is the default role of a user added to the organisation level?

Comment: I want to know, the moment that a new Org is created, what are the IAM roles and permissions including users and serviceAccounts (if applicable).

Answer (score -1):

We cannot determine which default permissions if any are assigned to a particular service account, but if you disable and then re-enable the API in your GCP project, the service account gets re-created with its default state.

To the second part of your question, as long as you have the “owner” role assigned to your account, you have full permission to revert back any changes you may have made to any account.

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be moved to be a comment to the question.